# Load xhtml in p:panels-primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a question.
How do I load a new xhtml file to p:panel using a button and still change the url. I would like to use a command button to load a new xhtml file to p:panel but i still want the websites url to change.

**Why I want to do this.**

I want to do this because i want my website to have multiple pages with my toolbar in each page. I don't want to have to duplicate the code for my toolbar in each page. -dose that make sense? If anyone know how to help please let me know.

**My code. index.xhtml**

Scroll done till you find p:panel with the class value "ClassPanel"
When a button in my toolbar is clicked i would like the p:panel to load a new xhtml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
       xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <h:head>
       <title>LEEXV</title>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <style>

        </style>

        <h:form > 

            <p:growl id="messages"/>

            <p:toolbar id="stickymenu" style=" max-height:60px; margin-top: auto; ">
                <f:facet name="left">

                     <f:facet name="left">



                </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="right">
                <p:growl id="growl" life="2000"/>
                <p:inputText  style="margin-right:40px;" placeholder="Search Crawly"/>
                <p:spacer width="10px;"/>

                     <p:commandButton value="Ajax Action" action="#{navigationView.gotoSecond}" style=" width: 90px; height: 40px;"/> 

                <p:spacer width="20px;"  />
                <p:commandButton id="Support" type="ComButton" style=" width: 90px; height: 40px;" value="Donate"/>
                <p:tooltip id="toolTipGrow" for="Support" value="Find out how you can help us help you!"
                           showEffect="clip" hideEffect="explode"  />

                <p:spacer width="20px;"/>
                <p:commandButton type="ComButton" style=" width: 90px; height: 40px;"  value="Update"/>
                <p:spacer width="20px;"/>
                <p:commandButton type="ComButton"   style="width: 90px; height: 40px; margin-top: 6px;"  value="Shop"/>


            </f:facet>




                </f:facet>


                <f:facet name="right">


                </f:facet>


            </p:toolbar>


            <p:sticky target="stickymenu"/>
        </h:form>



        <p:panel class="ClassPanel" >
        <ui:composition id="LoadNewpages"> 
           <ui:param id ="" name="defaultHeader"  value="#{HomeHtml.gotoSecond}" />
      </ui:composition> 


            </p:panel>


    </h:body>
</html>
```

**My code. newjsf.xhtml**

This is the code i would like to load in the panel.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"   
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  

      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  

      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="hello"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

**My code. NavigationView.java**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
 import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
@ManagedBean
public class NavigationView implements Serializable {

    public String gotoSecond() {
        return "newjsf";
    }
}
```

**If you don't understand please just try and help me with this part.. I have a history of asking bad question**

How do i use a button to load xhtml files. 
Basically, how do i load xhtml file dynamically to p:panel.

Comment: Just create a template.

Comment: @BalusC. I dont know how to do that. And also this question is not a duplicate. Please read through the whole dialogue instead of just the title. The title itself is a duplicate, but the dialogue is not.

Comment: The duplicate shows how. Note that duplicates are not about questions but about answers. It doesn't make sense to copypaste the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

try this, use include

```
<p:panel>
    <ui:include src="/page.xhtml"/>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: This is good but how do Ioad the file via button.

Comment: That's already linked in the duplicate.